# django login fail even when user is logged in

Tags: django

The below is my code for user login page.I am requesting user to login if login the show the logout link. But when ever I click on submit it open new home page and show link to login rather logout.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>please login</title>
</head>
    <body>
        {% if form.errors %}
            <p class="text-warning">Your login credential did not match</p>
        {% endif %}
        <form role="form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{% url 'boardgame_home_page' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Login"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

home page code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>board game</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{ user.username }}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <a href="{% url 'boardgames_logout' %}">logout</a>
    {% else %}
        <a href="{% url 'boardgames_login' %}">login</a>
    {% endif %}

    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <h1> Hi {{ user.unsername }} !</h1>
    {% else %}
        <p>welcome the my page , <a href="{% url 'boardgames_login' %}">click here to login</a> </p>
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

when I submit form it open home page but it ask for login even when user is login

settint.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'boardgame_home_page'
LOGIN_URL = 'boardgames_login'
LOGOUT_URL = 'boardgames_logout'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns += patterns('django.contrib.auth.views',
    url(r'^logout/','logout',{'next_page':'boardgame_home_page'},name='boardgames_logout'),
)

urlpatterns = patterns('django.contrib.auth.views',
    url(r'^$','login',{'template_name':'login/login.html'},name='boardgames_login'),
)
```

my home view
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

```
def home_page(request):
    return render_to_response('home/home.html')
```

Comment: Can you show your view code and `settings.py`?

Comment: Most likely the user you're passing to the template isn't the same as `request.user`.

Comment: Are you passing the `user` by any chance? Can you post the homepage view function as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that you are always passing the `RequestContext` to your views. The simplest way to do that is to use the [`render` shortcut](http://django.me/render), like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home_page(request):
    return render(request, 'home/home.html')
```

In your templates, by default, the currently logged in user is available as `{{ user }}`, but only if you pass in a `RequestContext`.

---

> Now I am getting `AnonymousUser`

This makes sense because your form is submitting to `boardgame_home_page`, and if the view code you submitted is the home page form, you are not actually logging anyone in.

Have a look at the [sample code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in) provided by django which shows you how to log a user in. You need similar logic in your home page view.

Finally, don't forget to [log a user out correctly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.logout) and then make sure that any view that requires a logged in user is property [decorated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

Comment: Now Iam getting AnonymousUser

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the user from request parameter.

Use the request parameter from home page template.

**home/home/html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>board game</title>
</head>
<body>

    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        <a href="{% url 'boardgames_logout' %}">logout</a>
    {% else %}
        <a href="{% url 'boardgames_login' %}">login</a>
    {% endif %}

    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        <h1> Hi {{ request.user.unsername }} !</h1>
    {% else %}
        <p>welcome the my page , <a href="{% url 'boardgames_login' %}">click here to login</a> </p>
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is wrong, because the request is already available in django templates; and this is not DRY at all.

Comment: Now Iam getting AnonymousUser